# checking a date between two dates gives wrong result

Tags: swift

I want to check if a date is between two dates but the result of my code is giving me wrong result can you check with me please. thank you for your help!
this is my code

```
extension Date{
func isBetweenDates(beginDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> Bool
{
    if self.compare(beginDate) == .orderedAscending
    {
        return false
    }

    if self.compare(endDate) == .orderedDescending
    {
        return false
    }

    return true
   }
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    let result0 =  "08-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!.isBetweenDates(beginDate: "01-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!, endDate: "09-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!)

    let result1 = "04-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!.isBetweenDates(beginDate: "06-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!, endDate: "08-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!)

    let result2 = "05-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!.isBetweenDates(beginDate: "01-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!, endDate: "04-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!)

    let result3 = "06-01-2018".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!.isBetweenDates(beginDate: "01-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!, endDate: "08-01-2019".date(format: "dd-MM-YYYY")!)

 }
```

and the output : result0 = true , result1 = true ,result2 =true ,result3 = false ,or they should be result0 = true , result1 = false ,result2 = false ,result3 = false ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, `Date` is comparable.

Which means you can compare two dates using this code...

```
date1 < date2
```

The compare function you are using is an old function that has come or from ObjectiveC. I presume you have found it on an old tutorial or something?

Anyway, just do something like...

```
return date1 < self && self < date2
```

In your function.

That will return true if `self` is between `date1` and `date2`.

Comment: Hey Fogmeister ! thank you for your reply, I tested your code and the output is : result0:false , result1:false , result2:false , result3:false but the first result must be true

Comment: change `dd-MM-YYYY`
 to `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: Btw you can use pattern match operator wit dates as well `func isBetween(start: Date, end: Date) -> Bool {
        return start...end ~= self
    }`